# Get service date and time from Event Viewer using Batch script

Tags: batch-file, windows-services, event-viewer

I have come up with a script that will restart a specific service and now I would like to know if there is a way I can get a service start time from event viewer using batch files.

Appreciate if anyone could give me the answer. Thanks!

Comment: for command line use, there is  a `eventvwr` command. Also `wevtutil` might be helpful.

Comment: The question shows total lack of research effort and I would vote to delete it any time but the task itself is interesting and seems useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [wevtutil](http://ss64.com/nt/wevtutil.html).

1. The service start/stop events are logged in the system event log, there are several ways to open it (use google). Clicking the events we can see a "service entered the running state" event with an ID 7036, let's use it to find the last start time of `Application Experience` service.

   Only one event is needed `/c:1` and since it's the last in the log let's **r**everse the **d**irection with `/rd:true`:

   `wevtutil qe system /rd:true /c:1 /q:"Event[EventData[Data[@Name='param1']='Application Experience'] and System[EventID=7036]]`

   The output is this xml blob:

   `<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Service Control Manager' Guid='{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}' EventSourceName='Service Control Manager'/><EventID Qualifiers='16384'>7036</EventID><Version>0</Version><Level>4</Level><Task>0</Task><Opcode>0</Opcode><Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2015-10-12T10:43:13.841899000Z'/><EventRecordID>4287264</EventRecordID><Correlation/><Execution ProcessID='800' ThreadID='1804'/><Channel>System</Channel><Computer>zOo</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data Name='param1'>Application Experience</Data><Data Name='param2'>running</Data><Binary>410065004C006F006F006B00750070005300760063002F0034000000</Binary></EventData></Event>`
2. Let's extract the date and time.

   First remove everything from the beginning up to `SystemTime=` with string replacement `set "xml=!xml:*SystemTime=!"`:

   > ='2015-10-12T10:43:13.841899000Z'/>.....................................(the rest of the string)

   Then split at `'` and `T` and `.` into tokens: `=`, `2015-10-12`, `10:43:13`, `841899000Z`, `/>....` and grab the 2nd and the 3rd:

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
       wevtutil qe system /rd:true /c:1 ^
           /q:"Event[EventData[Data[@Name='param1']='Application Experience'] and System[EventID=7036]]"
   ') do (
       set "xml=%%a" & set "xml=!xml:*SystemTime=!"
       for /f "delims='T. tokens=2,3" %%b in ("!xml!") do (
           echo Started at date: %%b time: %%c
       )
   )
   endlocal
   pause
   ```

   The date uses YYYY-MM-DD format, the time is 24-hour:

   > Started at date: 2015-10-12 time: 10:43:13